# Restrict access for a role in php

Tags: php

How would you code that? I've got the part where I can redirect certain roles to the pages but having a problem with restricting them to see a specific page.

I've tried this:

```
session_start();

if($_SESSION['username'] == "a@a.com"); 
{

header('location: student_listing');
die();
} 
else {
header('location: student_entry'); 
}
```

but it would say the site crashed because of too many redirects.

Comment: This is opinion based. can you show us your code if you tried something?

Comment: @ApulGupta i added some code

Comment: what problem are you facing? where are you trying to check role's privileges?

Comment: @ApulGupta i'm trying to restrict a@a.com from viewing the student listing page. But it won't go through.

Comment: just reverse the condition, as per your code you are trying to redirect user when username is `a@a.com`. It should be `!=` instead of `==`

Comment: you should look for RBAC in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the condition, as per your code you are trying to redirect user when username is a@a.com. It should be `!=` instead of `==`

```
<?php
$allowedUserNames = array('abc', 'ced', 'efj');
if( !in_array($_SESSION['username'], $allowedUserNames) )
{
 // redirect to unrestricted page
 header("location: UnRestrictedPage.php");
}

header("location: restrictedPage.php");
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine the code to let a@a.com direct to a certain page but restrict another?

Comment: yes, simply prepare an array of all allowed usernames & check for it. I am updating my code.

Answer (score -1):

You can restrict by setting if condition like this:

```
if($role=='specify role here')
{
    ----
}
else {

}
```

Can you post your code for more clarity what you did exactly.....

Comment: Try to use Javascript relocation method like window.location.href='file.php' instead of header